# Hide an attribute on product page (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For one of our Wordpress webshops we have created a custom field to assign a specific number (not SKU) to each product and variation.

How can we hide this custom field from customers?

Comment: There is many ways to make it work, but this is a real development and your question is too broad here on StackOverFlow, as you don't provide any code as base to start. I think that you will not get helped, except if a plugin already exist for that…

Comment: How did you create those custom fields? As long as you don't define them in your template they will not show up.. you need to provide some code..